# Python's new-style classes' base - `object` and `type`

Tags: python, object, types

According to the doc, `object` is all new-style classes' base class.

And AFAIK, the so-called new-style classes are just ones which can acquire some new fetures by inheriting `object`, right?

I thought `object` inherit `type` or use `type` as its `__metaclass__`, but `object.__bases__` gives me nothing, so where dose this `object` come from, and what's relationship bewteen it and `type`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, the type (i.e., metaclass) of `object`, a class, is `type`:

```
type(object) == type      # True
```

And since `object` is the base class, it has no parents of its own, as you'd expect:

```
object.__bases__ == ()    # True
```

`object` doesn't have a `__metaclass__` attribute because it doesn't need one: it uses the default metaclass, `type`.

Now it's a little confusing because `type` is in fact a subclass of `object`, which boggles the mind (how can `type` be derived from `object` when you need `type` to *construct* `object`?) but this is solved by a little hard-coding at the C level in the Python interpreter.

All this applies only to new-style classes, that is, those derived from `object`. In Python 3, all classes are new-style, so this applies globally in Python 3.

Comment: use the default metaclass? Do you mean, if I define a class (not inheriting `object`) without specifying its metaclass, then this class will be construted by `type`?

Comment: Yes. `type` is the metaclass Python uses if you don't specify a metaclass.

Comment: If you don't inherit from object, you will get an old-style class. If you're in Python 3, not inheriting from anything is the same as inheriting from object.

Comment: @yak, so in 3.0, all classes (inherit `object` or not ) are all the same?

Comment: Yes. `class A:`, `class A():`, `class A(object):` are all the same in 3.

Comment: @yak, then why not just abandon `object` in 3.0 ?

Comment: Because there must be some base class, for example to provide default implementation of magic methods like `__setattr__` or `__repr__`. You see `class A(object):` in Python code a lot because it is the form that gives you a new-style class in any Python version since 2.2 iirc.

Answer (score 3):

There are two concepts that could be helpful to keep in mind:

- everything in python is an object, including classes and metaclasses
- metaclasses are the constructors of classes, not their ancestors, so they do not appear in `__bases__`.

That means that `object` indeed has `type` as metaclass.

Just as a curiosity, the "paradoxical" part of the story is the `type`, which being a metaclass is also an object, but can't have itself as metaclass (it would be a bit of chicken-and-egg problem, if you think about it).

The paradox is solved with some C voodoo in the python source code, but I don't know much about it!

**EDIT:** (some example code)

```
>>> class MyMeta(type):
...     def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
...         return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
... 
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     __metaclass__ = MyMeta
...
```

Now observe that `obj` inherit from `object`

```
>>> obj = MyClass()
>>> MyClass.__bases__
(<type 'object'>,)
```

As for your question in the comments about `dir(obj)` doesn't output the `__metaclass__` attribute: **the reason is that `__metaclass__` is an attribute of the *class* not of its instantiated *object***. Note in fact that:

```
>>> dir(MyClass)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__metaclass__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
>>> MyClass.__metaclass__
<class '__main__.MyMeta'>
```

If you are interested in deepening your understanding of metaclasses, this is a classic SO question (with a very comprehensive answer, of course!):

[What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/100003/146792)

HTH!

Comment: Well, I actually think that `type` is `object`'s metaclass, but `dir(object)` doesn't even have an attribute as `__metaclass__`, why?

Comment: Because `type` is used by default. `__metaclass__` can be used to override it.

Comment: @Alcott - no worries. yak is spot-on with his remark. I'm adding one more link to my answer that should help you understanding metaclasses more if you are interested. :)

Answer (score 2):

You may find [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/04/03/the-fundamental-types-of-python-a-diagram/) and [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/03/30/python-objects-types-classes-and-instances-a-glossary/) posts interesting. Here's the diagram from the first:

[image]

Comment: Well, `object` is the base of `type`?

Comment: @Alcott: yes, it is. And `type` is the type of `object`. Read the linked articles and other relevant articles from the blog for a deeper explanation