# Defining a class which inherits from object

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance

I came across the following code snippet while reading some code in Python:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Base created"
```

What is this `object` that the above mentioned class is inheriting from? Now, I do understand that this is a 'new style' object defined from Python 2.2. However, I'm not sure I understand what exactly this `object` is. I have seen other classes in Python too inheriting from `object`.

Is this a class defined in Python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between old style and new style classes in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)

Comment: Look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=object#object

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python's new-style classes' base - \`object\` and \`type\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493655/pythons-new-style-classes-base-object-and-type)